# Power BI table conditional formatting Based on another Column

Tags: powerbi, report, dax

I Have these data

```
StartDate   ,EndDate
03/01/2022, 06/01/2022
09/01/2022, 24/01/2022
20/01/2022, 27/01/2022
10/01/2022,22/01/2022
03/01/2022, 17/01/2022
28/01/2022, 20/01/2022
22/01/2022, 18/01/2022
28/01/2022, 05/01/2022
06/01/2022, 30/01/2022
10/01/2022, 18/01/2022
20/01/2022, 14/01/2022
12/01/2022, 11/01/2022
23/01/2022, 01/01/2022
09/01/2022, 06/01/2022
```

I want to format the Endate column as follows

```
IF StartDate > EndDate THEN Blue else green
```

Expected output
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a measure:

```
Measure = IF(MAX(Table1[StartDate]) > MAX(Table1[EndDate]),1)
```

Go to cell elements for End Date

[image]

Complete as follows:

[image]

[image]